# How to Make Single Vertex Line Thicker or Thinner while Maintaining Original Position?

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, vertices

So I have this line that I created using single vertex points

[image]

I want to be able to make this thicker but maintain the original position

So far if I add a skin modifier it becomes huge like this

[image]

Then if I apply the scale it shrinks to here

[image]

But now if I want to make this even thinner, it doesn't shrink internally and instead it will either become shorter or longer depending on the axis I scale.

So instead of shrinking thinner, it just literally shrinks on the x axis or the y axis like this

[image]

Comment: In Edit mode, select All then CTRL-A.

Comment: whats the name or where is that option located on the menu tabs so I can understand what is happening?

Comment: In edit mode, Mesh > Transform > Skin Resize. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/transform/skin_resize.html